# PyQT5- Storing user input from a window prompt into a global variable

Tags: python, variables, input, pyqt5

I have a program that will store user input into a variable, check if it's an IP address and perform functions from there.

I want to add a window to make it look nicer and I'm having a hard time storing variables from the windows.

I would like to be able to -
-Gather user input and store it in a variable
-Use that variable in a function to check it if it matches an IP address and if so, execute if statements.

Here's example code from a tutorial that I've been playing around with-

```
    import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'IP / Domain'
        self.left = 10
        self.top = 10
        self.width = 640
        self.height = 480
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.getInteger()
        self.getText()
        self.getDouble()
        self.getChoice()

        self.show()   

    def getText(self):  

        userInput, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(self, "Get text", "Your name:", QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed and text != '':
            print(userInput)

def ipFormatChk(userInput): #input
pattern = r"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\." \
          r"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"
if re.match(pattern, userInput)
#do something
return

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:

```
import sys
import re
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QApplication, QWidget, QInputDialog, QLineEdit, 
                             QLabel, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton)
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QIcon

class App(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title  = 'IP / Domain'
        self.left   = 50
        self.top    = 50
        self.width  = 640
        self.height = 480

        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)

        self.label = QLabel()
        self.label.setStyleSheet("color: green; font: 16px;")

        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        layout.addWidget(self.label)
        layout.addWidget(QPushButton("Enter IP-address", clicked=self.getText))
        self.setLayout(layout)        

        #self.getInteger()
        #self.getText()
        #self.getDouble()
        #self.getChoice()

        self.show()   

    def getText(self):  

        userInput, okPressed = QInputDialog.getText(
                self, 
                "Input IP-address", 
                "Your IP-address:", 
                QLineEdit.Normal, "")
        if okPressed:                       # and userInput != '':
            #print(userInput)
            if userInput.strip():
                self.ipFormatChk(userInput)
            else:
                self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red; font: 24px;")
                self.label.setText("Input line is empty, enter IP-address")
        else:
            self.label.setText("")

    def ipFormatChk(self, userInput): 

        pattern = r"\b(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\." \
                  r"(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\.(25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9]|[01]?[0-9][0-9]?)\b"

        if re.match(pattern, userInput):
            additionalText = "This is IP-address"
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: lightgreen; font: 24px;")
        else:
            additionalText = "This is NOT an IP-address"
            self.label.setStyleSheet("color: red; font: 24px;")

        self.label.setText("{} <- {}".format(userInput, additionalText))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex  = App()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image]

Comment: Awesome, thanks! That works! I have some research to do now with this.

Comment: Good luck to you

Comment: As a follow up question, how would I add a drop down box with the options advanced and basic, and assign that to a variable?                                                             I'm trying to wrap my head around the GUI aspect which is driving me insane.